# Image tag not working in chrome only

Tags: java, image, jsp, barcode

img tag  not displaying on Chrome but working fine on IE and Firefox 
These are JSP Pages :

```
try {

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    Linear barcode = new Linear();
    barcode.setType(Linear.CODE11);
    barcode.setData("12345678912");
    barcode.setUOM(Linear.UOM_PIXEL);
    barcode.setX(3f);
    barcode.setY(75f);
    barcode.setLeftMargin(0f);
    barcode.setRightMargin(0f);
    barcode.setTopMargin(0f);
    barcode.setBottomMargin(0f);
    barcode.setResolution(72);
    barcode.setShowText(true);
    barcode.setTextFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 12));
    barcode.setRotate(Linear.ANGLE_0);
    File bimg = new File(barcode.getData());
    System.out.println(bimg.length());
    ImageIO.write(barcode.renderBarcode(), "jpeg", response.getOutputStream());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

%>

```
getbarcode.jsp
<img id="images" height="100px" width="300px" src="barcodecode.jsp">
```

I am using chrom Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) and NetBean 8.0.2

Comment: Hit F12 in Chrome and see what's going on. Retrieving an image will require a separate trip to the server so you should be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: k . i fount ... In Network tag i am getting "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
".. i search a lot on google..but still problem not solved.

Comment: i disabled or remove all extension and also unchecked "use a prediction service to load" in chrome....

Comment: Please , help to over come this problem. Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution :
I Just added ...

```
<%@page autoFlush="false" contentType="image/jpeg" %>
```

in my barcode.jsp page and replace

```
ImageIO.write(barcode.renderBarcode(), "jpeg", response.getOutputStream());
```

with

```
barcode.renderBarcode(response.getOutputStream());
```